# Two servers, severals domains, reverse DNS and blacklist

Tags: smtp, reverse-dns, blacklist

I will try to explain the context.

2 VPS with PLESK 11.5

The first (named vps67877.ovh.net - we call it v67) is a mail server (ip 37.187.33.38)
The second (named vps68789.ovh.net - we call it v68) is an hosting server. (ip 92.222.8.114)

When I have a customer, I create the hosting part in v68.
I create all the email adresses on v67.

For illustrate, we will take a domain we have : itbag.fr. Here is the DNS entries :

```
92.222.8.114 / 24   PTR itbag.fr.
blog.itbag.fr.  A   92.222.8.114
ftp.itbag.fr.   CNAME   itbag.fr.
imap.itbag.fr.  A   37.187.33.38
itbag.fr.   NS  sdns2.ovh.net.
itbag.fr.   NS  vps68789.ovh.net.
itbag.fr.   A   92.222.8.114
itbag.fr.   MX (10) mail.itbag.fr.
itbag.fr.   TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
mail.itbag.fr.  A   37.187.33.38
ns.itbag.fr.    A   92.222.8.114
pop.itbag.fr.   A   37.187.33.38
pop3.itbag.fr.  A   37.187.33.38
smtp.itbag.fr.  A   37.187.33.38
static.itbag.fr.    A   92.222.8.114
static2.itbag.fr.   A   92.222.8.114
static3.itbag.fr.   A   92.222.8.114
webmail.itbag.fr.   A   37.187.33.38
www.itbag.fr.   CNAME   itbag.fr.
```

I have several domains like that.

In my v67, I don't activate the DNS zone. I just say who are the servername :

```
114.ip-92-222-8.eu. (<= reverse DNS of v68)
sdns2.ovh.net. (<= By my provider)
```

Services works perfectily. But this week end, we have a spam attack... I don't know how and why, but we've got blacklisted by many DNSBL. I succeed on deleting all spams on v67, I succeed to contact all DNSBL for delist us...

When I check my configuration on MXTOOLBOX here is the report :

```
SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch   Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner     
SMTP Reverse Banner Check   OK - 92.222.8.114 resolves to 114.ip-92-222-8.eu

SMTP TLS    OK - Supports TLS.  
SMTP Connection Time    1.264 seconds - Good on Connection time     
SMTP Open Relay     OK - Not an open relay.     
SMTP Transaction Time   3.635 seconds - Good on Transaction Time
```

During my communications with some DNSBL, I get a tips for one of them :

> Please could you update the rDNS on this IP to be something more specific to
>   the sender and/or your organisation rather than the generic pattern that the
>   provider has assigned by default. You may need to contact your provider in
>   order to accomplish this rDNS change. Continuing to send mail from an IP with
>   a generic rDNS pattern is likely to affect your Cloudmark reputation score in
>   the future as well as your reputation with many ISPs and DNSbls.
>
> For instance mail.example.com would be considered far less generic than
>   208-83-136-1.sfo.example.com or hosted-by.example.com

But... I don't understand what they want me to do. Do I have to add a specific DNS entry like I don't know...

```
37.187.33.38.itbag.fr A mail.itbag.fr
```

I'm totaly lost...

Answer (score 3):

Let me skip your somewhat wild zone information and lead you to the the main problem as I see it:

Your Mailserver is

```
mail.itbag.fr
```

which resolves to

```
37.187.33.38
```

which has a reverse mapping to

```
38.ip-37-187-33.eu
```

This is not good in terms ob SBL/Antispam rules.

Further your mailserver greets:

```
# telnet 37.187.33.38 25
Trying 37.187.33.38...
Connected to 37.187.33.38.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 vps67877.ovh.net ESMTP Postfix
```

which is yet another hostname. Same is true for v68.

I would suggest bringing those names in line first and see if that helps the situation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My problem is, there is a lot of others domains on this server. mail.itbag.fr is the same as mail.la-ligne-web.com or mail.distridog.pro 

And this is the problem, i don't understand how to have the same name in order to be clean.

Comment: Try setting vps67877.ovh.net as PTR for 37.187.33.38. Do for v68 same with 92.222.8.114.